# GPIO ribbon cable with multiple connectors

Tags: gpio, cable

I need to connect multiple extension boards to single Pi3B+. I have checked that they will not be using the same GPIO signals. I am thinking of using a single ribbon cable with one female (for the Pi) and multiple male connectors for the other boards. I am puzzled however that I can't find anyone who's selling such, or even any mention of such being used.

There are replicator boards like [this one](https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/gpio-accessoires/triborg-plus-soldered) here, which seem to be doing the same thing. So the question is:

Can a single cable with multiple connectors be used instead of this replicator board, and if not - why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason not to use such a cable if you can find one.

I have used an old style 40 conductor IDE cable on the original Pi with the 26 pin header.  Note that 80 conductor IDE cables are not suitable.

Actually I'm wondering if my memory is faulty and I actually was using a floppy disk cable.

You would need to check that the cable does not reverse the ranks (odd numbered pins connected to even numbered pins).

Comment: Yes you can use ribbon cable with multiple connectors. Those boards provide the same functionality when you need something more rigid than cable.

Comment: And you can, of course, make a cable yourself. Ribbon cable and connectors are widely available